# How To Retain Selected Table When The Page Reloads On Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am new to laravel,

I have two tables and two buttons on laravel view blade,

I have used jquery to hide and show the relevant table on the click function,

But when the page reloads it won't retain the last active table,

Can someone suggest any ideas?

My code

```
<script> 
        $(function () {
            $('#btnAnalysis').on("click",function(){
               $(this).removeClass(); 
               $(this).toggleClass('btn btn-primary');
               $('#btnDicom').removeClass(); 
               $('#btnDicom').toggleClass('btn btn-normal'); 
               $('#dicomTable').hide();
               $('#analysisTable').show();   

            });

            $('#btnDicom').on("click",function(){
               $(this).removeClass(); 
               $(this).toggleClass('btn btn-primary');
               $('#btnAnalysis').removeClass(); 
               $('#btnAnalysis').toggleClass('btn btn-normal'); 
               $('#analysisTable').hide();
               $('#dicomTable').show();           
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page needs to reload, append a query string parameter to the url before the page refreshes. You can then check to see if the query string parameter is set or not, and then use that to show/hide/set active whatever you want.

Example blade:

```
@if (Input::get('active_table') === 'analysis')
    <script> 
    $(function () {
        $('#analysisTable').show();   
    })
    </script>
@else
    <script> 
    $(function () {
        $('#dicomTable').show();   
    })
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: with pleasure @ilhamzacky